# How to use oncompleteparams in Unity iTween plugin?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, callback, itween

I have code:

```
iTween.MoveTo(
gameObject,
iTween.Hash("x",_x,"z",_y, "time", 2.0f, "easetype",
iTween.EaseType.easeInExpo,
"oncomplete", "afterPlayerMove",
"oncompleteparams", iTween.Hash("value", _fieldIndex)
));
```

but I don't know how to use *oncompleteparams*.
There is no example in the official [manual](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/documentation.php).

How do you use oncompleteparams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/documentation.php#MoveTo) is the direct doc for the `Itween.MoveTo` function.

[image]

oncompleteparams expects `Object` as argument. This means that almost any datatype can be passed in to it. For example, `string`, `bool`, `int`, `float`, `double`, and `object instance` are one of datatypes that can be passed to it.

On the callback side, you make the callback function take Object as parameter. Inside the callback function, you cast the `Object` parameter to the type of datatype you passed to it.

Example:

```
"oncomplete", "afterPlayerMove",
"oncompleteparams", 5)
```

Callback:

```
public void afterPlayerMove(object cmpParams)
{
    Debug.Log("Result" + (int)cmpParams);
}
```

As you can see, we are passing 5 to the `oncompleteparams` function and 5 is an integer. In the `afterPlayerMove` callback function, we cast it back to integer to get the result.

---

In your example, you used `iTween.Hash` for the `oncompleteparams` so you must cast to `Hashtable` since iTween.Hash returns `Hashtable`. After that, to get the values in the Hashtable, you have to cast to that type too.

```
"oncomplete", "afterPlayerMove",
"oncompleteparams", iTween.Hash("value", _fieldIndex)
```

Callback:

Assuming that `_fieldIndex` is an `int`.

```
public void afterPlayerMove(object cmpParams)
{
    Hashtable hstbl = (Hashtable)cmpParams;
    Debug.Log("Your value " + (int)hstbl["value"]);
}
```

---

Finally, your code is unreadable. Simplify this code to make it easier for others to help you next time.

Complete simplified Example:

```
int _x, _y = 6;

//Parameter
int _fieldIndex = 4;
float floatVal = 2;
string stringVal = "Hello";
bool boolVal = false;
GameObject gObjVal = null;

void Start()
{
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable.Add("x", _x);
    hashtable.Add("z", _y);
    hashtable.Add("time", 2.0f);
    hashtable.Add("easetype", iTween.EaseType.easeInExpo);
    hashtable.Add("oncomplete", "afterPlayerMove");

    //Create oncompleteparams hashtable
    Hashtable paramHashtable = new Hashtable();
    paramHashtable.Add("value1", _fieldIndex);
    paramHashtable.Add("value2", floatVal);
    paramHashtable.Add("value3", stringVal);
    paramHashtable.Add("value4", boolVal);
    paramHashtable.Add("value5", gObjVal);

    //Include the oncompleteparams parameter  to the hashtable
    hashtable.Add("oncompleteparams", paramHashtable);
    iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, hashtable);
}

public void afterPlayerMove(object cmpParams)
{
    Hashtable hstbl = (Hashtable)cmpParams;
    Debug.Log("Your int value " + (int)hstbl["value1"]);
    Debug.Log("Your float value " + (float)hstbl["value2"]);
    Debug.Log("Your string value " + (string)hstbl["value3"]);
    Debug.Log("Your bool value " + (bool)hstbl["value4"]);
    Debug.Log("Your GameObject value " + (GameObject)hstbl["value5"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use `Arrays` directly. For example:

```
"oncomplete", "SomeMethod", 
"oncompleteparams", new int[]{value1, 40, value2}
```

Together with the method

```
void SomeMethod(int[] values) {
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Value1: {0}; Number: {1}; Value2: {2}",
        values[0], values[1], values[2]));
}
```

Of course you'll lose some readability here compared to the `HashTable` because you only have the indices to work with but there's no casting involved.